# how to make my pickup script not make gameobjects go through other objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

me and my friend are making a game and we need a script to pickup rigidbodys in the scene

and we found one but it doesnt work so we made one ourselfs but we are having some problems

so we are using `rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeAll;` and setting the objects transform to a HeldParent thats in front of the player but the held object goes through the walls and floor and interacts poorly with other objects in the scene

is there a way so it doesnt do this?

heres our current code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Grab : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform HeldParent;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    bool Grabbing;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {

        Grabbing = true;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
        this.transform.position = HeldParent.position;
        this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("HeldParent").transform;
        rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeAll;
    }
    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        Grabbing = false;
        this.transform.parent = null;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;
        rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
    }
}
```